# Stargazer producing various latex errors

Tags: r, dataframe, file-io, latex, stargazer

I am using `stargazer` to output regression results from `r` to `latex`. When I run the output in latex I see the results, but get many `Package array error`s. Here is my code. In R I use `stargazer` as follows:

```
stargazer(fe1, fe2, fe3,
               title="Between regression",
               align=TRUE, 
               df = FALSE, 
               dep.var.labels=c('depLabel'), 
               covariate.labels = c('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th') )
```

This produces many errors in `latex`that look like:

```
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (D): `c' used. ...5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} }
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (.): `c' used. ...5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} }
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (-3): `c' used. ...5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} }
```

and also many `Missing $ inserted` errors. Is there perhaps any package I need to add to my latex preamble? Or any other common workaround?

**Edit**  Here are the last lines of the `dput` of `fe1`:

```
"31495", "31496", "31497", "31498", "31499", "31500"), class = c("pindex", 
"data.frame"))), assign = c(0L, 1L, 1L), args = structure(list(
    model = "within", effect = "time", random.method = "swar", 
    random.dfcor = NULL, inst.method = "bvk"), .Names = c("model", 
"effect", "random.method", "random.dfcor", "inst.method")), aliased = structure(c(FALSE, 
FALSE), .Names = c("X1Dq", "X1DT")), call = plm(formula = Y1 ~ 
    X1, data = pdata1, effect = "time", model = "within")), .Names = c("coefficients", 
"vcov", "residuals", "df.residual", "formula", "model", "assign", 
"args", "aliased", "call"), class = c("plm", "panelmodel"))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the way to solve it by digging in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf): make sure to add `\usepackage{dcolumn}` in the latex preamble. Then I don't get any errors when compiling in latex.

Comment: Thanks you a million

Answer (score 4):

I want to make @splinter's answer more explicit since I just went through this same issue. To add it to the latex preamble when using knitr / rmarkdown, you need to put it here:

```
---
title: "Project Tables"
author: "Kelsey E. Gonzalez"
date: "January 20, 2020"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{dcolumn}
output:
  pdf_document: default
---
```

The header-includes is an optional setting not commonly used but will force the dcolumn to be loaded by latex.